# Python Text Adventure Movement:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the process of writing this text adventure and I am having trouble with something...
I am trying to get it so the input allows me to write "Go (direction)" but whenever I put the word "Go" into my movements or my conditional it doesn't accept the command. I'm kinda confused and don't need help with the whole thing, just this one part. I have tried changing the input allowance, the directions in the dictionary, and the condition in the while loop, but to no avail.

Here is my current code! :) (The commented out part is my storyline, it's commented out because it reads slowly every time I go to run the file).

EDIT: I figured it out, I ended up splitting the input and it accepted the second part of the input. IDK if that's the best way, but it worked!

````
# import sys

# def delay_print(s): 
#     for c in s:
#         sys.stdout.write(c)
#         sys.stdout.flush()
#         time.sleep(0.05)

# def go_delay_print(s):
#     for c in s:
#         sys.stdout.write(c)
#         sys.stdout.flush()
#         time.sleep(0.50) #I found these statements online so the game has a better flow/feel to it. They allow print statements to be typed out instead of just displayed all at once. I also figured out how to get the user to continue only when they hit enter (input("Press enter to continue..."))

# user_name = input() #I want the user to input their name here so that I can use it better in the game. They will have text strings that include their name when the narrator, themself, is talking (kind of like an internal dialogue).

# def show_instructions(): 
#    #print a main menu and the commands
#    print("Exam Day: The Game")
#    print("Check off all the task on your list to win the game, or fail the exam!")
#    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
#    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")





# #all story
# def story():
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     delay_print("It’s the first day of school finals and you open your eyes, not to the sound of your alarm going off, but to a pitch-black room.\n")
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     delay_print("You lost power overnight!\n")
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     delay_print("Almost as quickly as you realized the power was missing, it returned.\n")
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     delay_print("Only for you to see the time on your computer, it’s 8:15 A.M. and your first final is at 8:45, luckily your class is the next building over.\n")
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     delay_print("With only 30 minutes left to shower, get dressed, gather your things for the day, and eat you start a list.\n")
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     delay_print("“To do:\n")
#     delay_print("•Shower in the bathroom\n")
#     delay_print("•Put on clothes in the bedroom \n")
#     delay_print("•Make breakfast in the kitchen\n")
#     delay_print("•Get backpack from the study\n")
#     delay_print("•Grab books from the study and put them into backpack\n")
#     delay_print("•Put pens and pencils from the drawer into backpack”\n")
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     delay_print("The final task is to leave your house, you have 30 minutes…\n")
#     input("Press enter to continue...")
#     go_delay_print("Go!\n")
#     show_instructions() #after story this will send player to instructions


# story() #starts story then leads to instructions

# A dictionary for the Exam Day
# the dictionary links a room to other rooms
# starter inventory empty due to not having items

inventory = []
rooms = {
    'Bedroom': {'South': 'Bathroom', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Clothes'},
    'Bathroom': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'Shower'},
    'Kitchen': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Outside', 'East': 'Living Room', 'South': 'Study', 'item': 'food'},
    'Study': {'North': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Packpack'},
    'Living Room': {'North': 'Backroom', 'West': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Notebook and Pen'},
    'Back Room': {'South': 'Living Room', 'item': 'Books'},
    'Outside': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Exam'} #The end goal is to get all the items so you can be ready for your exam
     
}


room = 'Bedroom' #Game starts here


def new_room(room, direction):
    current_room = room #current room will be used for other commands below (such as room player is in)
    for i in rooms:
        if i == room:
            if direction in rooms[i]:
                current_room = rooms[i][direction]
    return current_room


movement_types = ["North", "South", "West", "East", "Exit"]

def show_status():
    (print('----------------------------------------------\n', "Current room is {}\n".format(room), '----------------------------------------------\n', 'Inventory: {}\n'.format(inventory), '----------------------------------------------'))

while True:
    show_status()
    movement = input("Input direction (go North, go South, go East, or go West) to move. Otherwise enter exit to end\n")
    movement = movement.capitalize()

    if (movement in 'Exit'):
        exit(0)
    if (movement in movement_types):
        current_room = new_room(room, movement) #update current room to the new romm based off of current room and direction inputted
        if current_room == room: #if current room is already this room
            print("Can't go that way. Try again") #raise error/tell player they can't go that way and have them try again
        else:
            room = current_room #else update the room with current room based off of above current_room
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Try again") #invalid input; Player wrote something wrong```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use this - it does not seem you are using `inventory` for anything:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("go[ ]+(\w+)", re.IGNORECASE)

while True:
    show_status()
    movement = input("Input direction (go North, go South, go East, or go West) to move. Otherwise enter exit to end\n")
    movement = pattern.findall(movement)[0].capitalize()

    if movement == 'Exit':
        exit(0)
    elif movement in movement_types:
        current_room = new_room(room, movement) #update current room to the new romm based off of current room and direction inputted
        if current_room == room: #if current room is already this room
            print("Can't go that way. Try again") #raise error/tell player they can't go that way and have them try again
        else:
            room = current_room #else update the room with current room based off of above current_room
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Try again") #invalid input; Player wrote
```